# Can I use autoquery with asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

The project I work on uses asp.net web api, it uses ORMLite to connect database. I am wondering if I could uses autoquery without setup the servicestack server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) generates ServiceStack Services behind scenes so ServiceStack is required but if you’re using ASP.NET Core you’ll be able to use ServiceStack and Web API together in the same App at different routes.

Comment: Can I use ASP.NET and ServiceStack in the same app at different routes ?

Comment: @StevenLi if you’re referring to classic ASP.NET see docs on [Running ServiceStack side-by-side with another Framework](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework).